# SDK Directory issue

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

i got a message while import a existing project to android studio. below i attached it

The SDK path
'D:\android-sdk'
does not belong to a directory.

Android Studio will use this Android SDK instead:
'C:\Users\M.T.M Nafrin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'
and will modify the project's local.properties file.

Comment: You just click ok on that and everything will work fine. Its normal.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.